# How can I pass void *payload object in git_index_add_all() method of libgit2 library?

Tags: libgit2

I am running libgit2 v0.23.0. I am calling method [git_index_add_all](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#v0.23.0/group/index/git_index_add_all) which takes following parameters:

- git_index * index
- const git_strarray * pathspec
- unsigned int     flags
- git_index_matched_path_cb    callback
- void *   payload

I am not able to get how do I need to create last `void *payload parameter`

My code is :

```
 git_index *idx = NULL;
 git_index_matched_path_cb matched_cb = NULL;
 int error = 0;
 error = git_index_open(&idx, "repofolder/.git/index");
 char *paths[] = {"repofolder/*"};
 git_strarray arr = {paths, 1};
 error = git_index_add_all(idx, &arr, GIT_INDEX_ADD_DEFAULT,matched_cb, ?);
```

could anybody suggest me, what should be way to create or get payload type object ?

Answer (score 2):

The `payload` argument is the standard way of creating a closure in C. Your callback will receive whatever pointer you put in as its `payload` argument. It should be a pointer to whatever variable/structure you need for the callback to do its work.

If you don't need any data, then pass in `NULL`.

Comment: When I am using NULL like   `git_index_add_all(idx, &arr, GIT_INDEX_ADD_DEFAULT,matched_cb, NULL);` it's crash my program with error **Assertion failed! File :..\src\repository.c Line:1874**

Comment: Have you checked what that assertion is? The index you create in your example code is a new one, not associated with any repository, so the add-all operation makes no sense there.

Comment: Suppose I have made any changes in my local repo, then how can I get index or create/update new index ? In example I am using `git_index_open()` method to get idx.

Comment: Ask the repository for the index with [`git_repository_index()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#v0.23.0/group/repository/git_repository_index)

Comment: Thanks it's work now...It is not crashing now. But `git_index_add_all()` method not changing any index, object under .git folder. As I know `git_index_add_all()` should work equivalent as as `git add .`

Comment: libgit2 does not implement git commands, so it should not work the same way. The operations happen to the index object in memory. If you want to persist the changes, you can store the in-memory structure to the disc with [`git_index_write()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#v0.23.0/group/index/git_index_write)